# Pass data between controllers using method void

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller

I need to pass values from one controllaro to a method from another controller.

or is there another way to pass data to an object so that object takes care of doing all the operations receiving values from other controllers

**PRIMARY CONTROLLER**

```
DateTime TimeLog = DateTime.Now;
LogController.Insert(TimeLog);
```

**LOG CONTROLLER**

```
using PROGRAM.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace PROGRAM.Controllers
{
    public class LogController : Controller
    {
        Entities db = new Entities();

        internal static void Insert(DateTime TimeLog)
        {
            LogModel log = new LogModel();
            log.User = Session["User"].ToString();
            log.TimeLog = TimeLog;
            db.Log_Arqueo.Add(log);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

**ERROR**

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Status deleted
Error CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static 'Controller.Session' field, method, or property PROGRAM\Controllers\LogController.cs 17 Active
```

Comment: don't do a static method.

Comment: @DanielA.White removing static I get in the PRIMARYController


`Error CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'LogController.Insert (DateTime)'`

Comment: you have to create an instance of your class then.

Comment: @DanielA.White do you have any method to share me?

Comment: You're asking how to create an instance of a class? That's something any basic C# tutorial should cover. It's just a matter of invoking a constructor. Also - you shouldn't have one controller call another. If there's logic that needs to be done, stick it in a separate class. Controllers can call it there.

Comment: @mason do you have a example?

Comment: @rodrigo.rodriguez An example of what? Please be specific in what you're asking about.

Comment: @mason the example of how you should do these procedures

Comment: Create a new class. Put your logic in a method in that class. In your controller, create an instance of that class and invoke that method. I can't stress enough - these are basic C# concepts. I'm not trying to belittle you. But if these sound like foreign concepts to you, then you need to to spend some more time learning the basics. Otherwise this is going to devolve into an endless cycle of you asking us for help and us explaining basic concepts that a tutorial would cover much better. That's not a good use of your time, our time, or this site.